# Missing Constraint JavaSE-1.8 Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment

Tags: java, manifest, osgi-bundle

I am trying to upgrade a maven plugin project from Java 1.7 to 1.8. I have done the following change in the pom.xml:

```
<requiredExecutionEnvironment>JavaSE-1.8</requiredExecutionEnvironment>
```

However, I get the following error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded the version of osgi and it worked.